# Is the factory_girl_rails gem outdated and/or no longer maintained?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

[The factory_girl_rails documentation](https://rubygems.org/gems/factory_girl_rails)  states the following:

> factory_girl_rails provides integration between factory_girl and rails 3 (currently just automatic factory definition loading)

Also, as of this moment: the latest version, 4.5.0, was released in October 2014.

If I am using Rails 4 or later, should I avoid using this gem then since the documentation states bluntly that it is built for Rails 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nope**.

You can definitely use `factory_girl`, because it is **awesome** and actively maintained. For example, I am using `Rails 4.2.3` and `ruby-2.2.2` along with `factory_girl-4.5.0` which is working nicely.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails#rails) says: Supported Rails versions are listed in [Appraisals](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails/blob/master/Appraisals).
Rails 4.2 is listed.